# Seeing locked files as read only in Box API

Tags: windows, locking, readonly, box-api

I am using Box and Box Sync in Windows 7, and have a client who wants to be able to lock a file in Box and have Box Sync propagate that to Windows by making the file read-only.  I know that there is some property transferred from Box to Windows when the file is brought in, because the icon for the file changes to show a small lock in its lower-left hand corner.
Does anyone know how to access that attribute and apply it to making the files read only, in Windows?

Thanks,

Danielle

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently exposed in the [file object of the API](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-file-object-2). We may consider adding this attribute in the future. There may be some things you can do OS-level to restrict the local copy to be read-only; it's probably best to check elsewhere on StackOverflow regarding how to do that.